# topological spaces with The FDS property?

Tags: general-topology

I have difficulty with bellow Theorem that was asked by one of users:

The class of spaces in which all compact subsets are closed is **$KC$ space.**

A space $X$ is said to have **the FDS property** if each infinite subset $A ⊆ X$
contains an infinite subset with only finitely many accumulation points (in $X$).

**Lemma :Each infinite subspace of a $KC$-space contains an infinite discrete subspace**

> **Theorem**A compact KC-space of cardinality less than $c$ has the FDS-property (and
>   hence is sequentially compact).

**Proof**: Suppose that $(X, τ)$ is a compact $KC$-space and $|X| < c$. We assume to the contrary that $X$ does not have the FDS- property and so there is some countably infinite subset $A ‎\subseteq‎ X$ such that every infinite subset of $A$ has infinitely many accumulation points in $X$. By Lemma above, without loss of generality, we can assume that $A$ is discrete and that $cl_X (A) = X$. Let $x \in X - A$; if every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ is such that $A - U$ is finite,then $A ‎‎‎\cup \{x\}$ is compact, hence closed in $X$ and so $x$ is the unique accumulation point of $A$, a contradiction. Thus we can choose an open neighbourhood $V$ of $x$, such that $A - V$ is infinite. The closed subspace $X - V$ of $X$ is compact and $A$ is countable, and hence Lindelöf, and so $A ‎‎‎\cup (X - V )$ is Lindelöf. This in its turn implies that $A ‎‎‎\cup (X - V )$ is not countably compact, for otherwise it would be compact, but being a proper dense subspace of $X$, it is not closed in $X$, a contradiction. Thus there is a discrete set $D ‎\subseteq‎ A ‎‎‎\cup (X - V )$ which is closed in $A ‎‎‎\cup (X - V )$. However, since $X - V$ is compact, only a finite number of points of D lie in $X - V$ and hence $D \cap‎ V$ is infinite and all its accumulation points (by our hypothesis, an infinite number in $X$) must lie in $V$ ; that is to say, $cl_{X} (D \cap‎ V ) ‎\subseteq‎ V$ .
Thus we have constructed two infinite sets $D \cap‎ V$ and $A - V$ whose closures are disjoint
in $X$. Since $D \cap‎ V ‎\subseteq‎ A$, each of these sets has the property that every infinite subset has an infinite number of accumulation points and the above argument can be repeated using $D \cap‎ V$ and $A - V$ in place of $A$. A standard binary tree argument can now be used to show that $|X| ≥ c$.

> **Why has been said**: ** without loss of generality** , we can assume that $A$ is discrete and that $cl_X (A) = X$?

**Why are these  true :**

1- $|X| ≥ c$ and

2- there is a discrete set $D ‎\subseteq‎ A ‎‎‎\cup (X - V )$ which is closed in $A ‎‎‎\cup (X - V )$?

Comment: Do you refer to this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456198/a-compact-kc-space-of-cardinality-less-than-c-has-the-fds-property?

Comment: Here is also link to the paper in question: http://www.jams.or.jp/scm/contents/e-2004-5/2004-46.pdf